# Angular - Angular Material - Drag and drop questions

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular-cdk

I'm using the drag and drop functionality of Angular Material CDK for a project and I would like to get the position X and Y of my objects.

I would like also to move my object with TypeScript and place it in X 25px and Y 32px. How may I achieve that?

Thank's in advance.
Jérémy

Comment: You should be more specific on your question, also posting the code you're using, explaining what you tried so far and the issue you are facing.

Comment: I haven't issues, I would like do this, but i don't know how. I did not try anything, I do not know what to try !

Comment: If you only want to place an element at an X and Y position, you may do that with CSS. If you need it to be dynamic, you may bind to style property inside html template (this is pure angular, with no angular material). If you're looking to use cdk drag and drop functionality, you should start looking at the [official docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview), checking the examples provided and the entire API. [This article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-drag-and-drop-with-the-angular-material-cdk-2e0237857290) seems to have further information that may help.

Comment: I've added additional tags to your question for better visibility and rephrased it a little bit. Also, you should provide more information, be clearer on what you need and update the question with new info or tries.

Comment: Thank's,  I have use exemples for do a drag and drop, but I would like can drag with my mouse or my finger and with the TS code. How do that ? Thank's in advance. Jérémy